# Is it possible to create a LAN between Raspberry Pi, Mikrotik Access Point and a laptop?

Tags: routing, lan, raspberry-pi

I need to create a LAN communication between my Windows laptop and a Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to create a network with a following gear and configuration:
Windows Laptop - (Wi-Fi) - Mikrotik Groove Metal - (ethernet cable) - Raspberry Pi. No other clients or sources and special routing tweaks needed. Just a good old LAN connection in within this gear config.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Mikrotik Groove Metal *is* what is commonly called a "WiFi router", I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Configure both the Windows laptop and the Rasp Pi to use DHCP on their respective connections.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Wireless interface on the Mikrotik to be a "ap bridge" and configure the settings such as SSID and security profile. Then make sure you have both the Ethernet Interface and Wireless Interface in the same bridge. I would hard set IPs on the Pi, Mikrotik, and Windows computers (192.168.88.XXX) so its easier to access them (say from the laptop to the Pi using SSH). That's one good thing about Mikrotik is that you can configure them how ever works best for you.